# add_theme_page is not working

Tags: theme-development

Newbie in wordpress coding. please tell how to create theme option pages.

```
function my_plugin_menu() {

    add_theme_page('Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'edit_theme_options', 'theme-option-slug' , 'settings_page'); 
}

function settings_page()
{
    echo "aa";  
}
```

Comment: The Codex is your friend: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created the callback function and the function for adding the Theme page, but you also have to tell WordPress when to call your function `my_plugin_menu`. You can do this by hooking into `admin_menu`.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');
```

This way WordPress knows that when it reaches the Scripts for `admin_menu`, it also has to execute your code, thus adding your Theme Page.

More information on this is available on the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page).

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention **add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');** but still no result

Comment: Did you check the capabilities for the user where you are testing this?

Comment: i am super admin

Comment: The Code you wrote above works perfectly fine. You may be Super Admin, but you can still lack the capability of `edit_theme_options`, those are two different things. Ehat happens when you load the page yourdomain.com/wp-admin/themes.php?page=theme-option-slug ?

Comment: Nice. So it was maybe just a caching problem :)

Comment: showing - You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Comment: As I asked, are you sure you have the capability of `edit_theme_options`? You can also try to set the required capability to `edit_posts` to see if it works then.

Comment: if i don't have capability of **edit_theme_options** how it works on other themes?

Comment: If you don't have the capability, this page will not show. if you have it, it will show. What did you change to before, when it worked?

Comment: i switch the theme. paste same code, its work. then i switch to previous theme its showing same problem. not showing tab and by using slug it showing - You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.